# Merging HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, merge

I found this nice footer in codepen (https://codepen.io/mfritsch/pen/xbJMaa) and I want to use it in my website footer .Please help me to merge the HTML and CSS.

HTML Code :

```
> <span>
>     Made with <i class="fa fa-heart pulse"></i> in <a href="https://www.google.de/maps/place/Augsburger+Puppenkiste/@48.360357,10.903245,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x479e98006610a511:0x73ac6b9f80c4048f"
> target="_blank">Auxburg</a> </span>
```

CSS Code:

```
body
  background: #e9e9e9
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif
  text-align: center
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale

span
  color: #666
  font-size: 12px
  display: block
  position: absolute
  bottom: 10px
  position: absolute
  width: 90%
  left: 50%
  top: 45%
  bottom: auto
  right: auto
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%)
  text-align: center
  a
    color: #000000
    text-decoration: none
  .fa
    color: #E90606
    margin: 0 3px
    font-size: 10px
    animation: pound .35s infinite alternate
    -webkit-animation: pound .35s infinite alternate

@-webkit-keyframes pound
  to
    transform: scale(1.1)


@keyframes pound
  to
    transform: scale(1.1)
```

Thanks

Comment: _“Please help me to merge the HTML and CSS.”_ - please explain what _exactly_ you need help with then. Please go read [ask]. Show us what you tried, and give a proper explanation of how it did not achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference where your CSS file is at in your directory in your HTML file. Use the  tag.

Answer (score 0):

You copied a Sass script instead of a CSS below is the equivalent CSS for it

```
body {
  background: #e9e9e9;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

span {
  color: #666;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 90%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 45%;
  bottom: auto;
  right: auto;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
}
span a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
span .fa {
  color: #E90606;
  margin: 0 3px;
  font-size: 10px;
  animation: pound 0.35s infinite alternate;
  -webkit-animation: pound 0.35s infinite alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pound {
  to {
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
}
@keyframes pound {
  to {
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
}
```

Another thing is that it uses a Font Awesome Icon and Roboto Font so you need to include this in your html header

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,400italic,700italic,700" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the CSS you are using is [SASS](https://sass-lang.com), this is a [CSS preprocessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CSS_preprocessor), it needs to be compiled to CSS first, you can easily do it on Codepen:
[image: view compiled CSS]

Now if you want your CSS directly in your HTML, just insert it in a `style` tag.
The Codepen link you sent was using two external stylesheets as you can see in `Settings > CSS > Add External Stylesheets/Pens`. You need to add those with the `link` tag.

See the below code snippet:

```html
<span> Made with <i class="fa fa-heart pulse"></i> in <a href="https://www.google.de/maps/place/Augsburger+Puppenkiste/@48.360357,10.903245,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x479e98006610a511:0x73ac6b9f80c4048f" target="_blank">Auxburg</a> </span>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,400italic,700italic,700">
<style>
body {
  background: #e9e9e9;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

span {
  color: #666;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 90%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 45%;
  bottom: auto;
  right: auto;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
}
span a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
span .fa {
  color: #E90606;
  margin: 0 3px;
  font-size: 10px;
  animation: pound 0.35s infinite alternate;
  -webkit-animation: pound 0.35s infinite alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pound {
  to {
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
}
@keyframes pound {
  to {
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
}
</style>
```